# how to store loss value in array in tensorflow object detection API

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow object detection API. I want a loss value to calculate some other metrics using my own dataset. I don't know how to get value from slim. I don't want to use tensorboard. 
this is under object_detection/trainer.py

```
slim.learning.train(
    train_tensor,
    logdir=train_dir,
    master=master,
    is_chief=is_chief,
    session_config=session_config,
    startup_delay_steps=train_config.startup_delay_steps,
    init_fn=init_fn,
    summary_op=summary_op,
    number_of_steps=(
        train_config.num_steps if train_config.num_steps else None),
    save_summaries_secs=120,
    sync_optimizer=sync_optimizer,
    saver=saver)
```

I tried to get the value from tf.event like this.

```
for e in tf.train.summary_iterator(path_to_events_file):
    for v in e.summary.value:
        if v.tag == 'loss' :
            print(v.simple_value)
```

But there is no tag for loss value. Not sure how object_detection API stored the value in tf.event and tensorboard read it. I am new in tensorflow so any help is appreciate. Thank you so much in advance.

I want this store this real-time loss value

```
INFO:tensorflow:global step 1558: loss = 3.3541 (0.242 sec/step)

INFO:tensorflow:global step 1559: loss = 3.3310 (0.235 sec/step)

INFO:tensorflow:global step 1560: loss = 3.1000 (0.243 sec/step)

INFO:tensorflow:global step 1561: loss = 2.7938 (0.246 sec/step)

INFO:tensorflow:global step 1562: loss = 3.9739 (0.240 sec/step)

INFO:tensorflow:global step 1563: loss = 2.7298 (0.256 sec/step)

INFO:tensorflow:global step 1564: loss = 3.5494 (0.249 sec/step)

INFO:tensorflow:global step 1565: loss = 2.7987 (0.237 sec/step)

INFO:tensorflow:global step 1566: loss = 3.3477 (0.251 sec/step)
```